# python input and def problems

Tags: python, input

i start learning python and i tried to make a function to put number between 1-12 (months) and it should return the days in this month but when i run the code its not let me put a number without anny error

```
def month_days(months,days):
    choise = input("select number:")
    months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

    if choise == months[0,2,4,6,7,9,11]:
        return days[0,2,3,4,6,7,9,11]
    elif choise == months[1]:
        return days[1]
    else:
        return days[3,5,8,10]
```

i know there r better options to do it and ill be happy if someone give me another ideas.

i tried to play of other options but its not what i meant to do

Comment: You should better learn a bit more Python yet. The first mistake is that `input` always returns a string which is never equal to an integer number.

Comment: `months[0,2,4,6,7,9,11]` is not valid Python. On the other hand, it seems that whatever number the user chooses, you want to return the value from `months` whose index is a function of that number (should the user count January as month 0??). So, there's no need to use `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary.

```
days_map = {
    1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30,
    7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31
    }

def month_days():
    choise = input("select number:")

    if int(choise) in days_map:
        return days_map[int(choise)]
    else:
        return 'not a valid number'

print(month_days())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dictionary comprehension with range(12). Also, you should check that all characters in the user input string are digits (with the function isdigit()), and that the input you casted to an integer is between 1-12, before trying to access the dictionary otherwise you could run into a key error. I also called the function after an invalid input allowing the user to try again.

```
def month_days():
    choice = input("Select month (as an integer):")
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    months = {i + 1: days[i] for i in range(12)}
    # print(months)
    if all(c.isdigit() for c in choice):
        choice_int = int(choice)
        assert(choice in range(1,13))
        return months[choice_int]
    else:
        print("Please input an integer from 1-12")
        month_days()

print(month_days())
```

this would give you:

```
Select month (as an integer):12
31
```

and if you were to print months:

```
{1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}
```

Comment: Note you can more simply define `months` with `dict(enumerate(days, start=1))`.